# How to properly end a SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

How can I properly end this workflow?

- I want to start a workflow whenever the `Returned Device` column is
  changed to `NO`.
- Then, if `Returned Device` equals `NO` and the `Returned Date` is
  overdue (less than `Today`), send an email to the user who was
  issued a device `Assigned To`.
- Now, (I want to end the workflow) When `Returned Device` is set to `YES`, END workflow.

Where do I Transition to End of Workflow? Do I even need to? I want to avoid workflow instances running in the background if I don't need to.

[image]

**List:**
[image]

***This is for SharePoint Online***

**Updates:**
[image]

**Final:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in the **Go To "stage"** action add IF statement and select **In Progress** and **End of Workflow**. This action add to all ends of your workflows (if you have If statement there can be more of them)

[image]

[image]

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: At which point is the ‘Transition to stage’ evaluated and how frequent (ie. everytime Loop 1 is evaluated etc...)?

Comment: its in every Stage at the end, you are here chosing the next Stage it will do (or the end of WF) dont forget to mark it as answer. thanks

Comment: I added another screenshot with the IF statement in Transition to stage.

Comment: i added an if statement to the `Transition to stage` but the workflow doesnt end when I change Returned Device to `YES`. I re-published the workflow and I terminated the old ones with no success. Anything you can think of?

Comment: ok, so try create new Stage when you will end WF and in IF statement go to this new Stage, I dont know why, it should be working, try it this way, you can also add Log action to the IF statement so you will see in log where it going.

Comment: Got it. I created a final stage so the status on the list shows completed. Otherwise, the workflow ends but the status shows `In Progress`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice, you're welcome :)